# If two sets have the same cardinality and there is a one-to-one mapping, then is the mapping automatically also onto?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1) If two sets have the same cardinality and there is a one-to-one mapping, then is the mapping automatically also onto?

2) If two sets have the same cardinality and there is an onto mapping, then is the mapping automatically also one-to-one?

I believe that these statements are true, but I am unsure how to prove. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take any two elements of set $A$ and assume both map to one element of set $B$ and see if you arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Your question, as currently stated, doesn't make much sense. Sets cannot be "one-to-one" or "onto"; mappings between sets may possess or not such properties.

Comment: Now, after the edit, the question makes sense. The answer is that both statements are true for finite sets, but generally false for infinite sets.

Answer (score 1):

No, to both questions. Simply consider $\mathbb{Z}$ and $2\mathbb{Z}$ which is a counterexample for both cases. The statements, however, are true for finite cardinalities. You can prove it e.g. by the pigeon hole principle.